# Json objects built from model in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user object and message object where there is user_id in message model. When I do Message.find(1) how can I get user object as part of the json object or what is the correct way to inject? So it would have the whole user object instead of just user_id

I know I can get it from @message.user but not sure what is the correct way of injecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
Message.find(1).to_json(:include => :user)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `Message.find(1, :include => :user)`, the `user` object associated with the `message` object also gets loaded. This is called eager loading. Two objects get loaded with one query. You can then build the Json object with that. [Read about eager loading!](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)